# Correctly format included javascript code when rendering

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, view

My project listens to a port. Whenever it receives a request, it reads a couple of XML-files and returns certain chunks of Javascript, concatenated. My problem is that the code is HTML-formatted and put inside the header when rendering the **.ejs** file. It's built using Express and MVC, by the way.

The chunks are defined inside separate class methods like this:

```
Module.prototype.opens = function () {
   var returnvar = "var myobject=function(){var D=\"undefined\",r=\"object\",S=\"
   ... etc
```

As you can see, I've escaped the code in advance to avoid causing the quotes, backslashes and more to terminate the variable string unexpectedly.

When outputting in console.log() just before rendering the view-page, the code looks fine: `var myobject=function(){var D="undefined",r="object",S=" ...`

However, when the view is rendered, the source code looks like this:

```
var myobject=function(){var D=&#34;undefined&#34;,r=&#34;object&#34;,S=&#34;
```

I've tried replacing, unescaping etc. but since I (as mentioned before) am outputting the code to console for debugging purposes, just before I pass it to the view, it indicates that the conversion happens in the rendering process.

The renderer looks like this:

```
var readSymbolicsXMLCallback = function(data) {
    res.render('index', {
        id: req.params.id,
        embedcode: data
    });
}
```

The view simply contains this:

```
<%= embedcode %>
```

Any ideas to why this is happening and how to prevent/correct it? And preferably in a low-CPU intensive way if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EJS readme](https://github.com/mde/ejs#tags) shows the different tags you can use in your templates. `<%=` will escape the contents whereas `<%-` will not, so use the latter.